# How to do build a complex query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My table called Approvals has following columns:
Id, Approvers, PendingAtLevel

Sample value of Approvers looks like this `[["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]` `which is basically a 2d array`.

And pendingatlevel indicates where my request is pending. If pending at level is 2 this means request can be approved by anyone of the following `"cat","bat" or "rat"`.

Below is my sample data of table:

```
Id  PendingAtLevel  Approvers
1   1   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
2   2   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
3   3   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
4   1   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
5   1   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
6   2   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
7   1   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
8   2   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
9   1   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
10  2   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
11  3   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
12  1   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
13  1   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
14  2   [["ash","bash","rash"],["cat","bat","rat"],["boss"]]
```

I am trying to build a api wherein I can pass the username e.g "boss" as input and it will return me requests pending for approval with "boss"

I want to write a sql query for postgresql query wherein when I supply query param `boss` and it will return me 3rd and 11th record.

This is postgresql 9.x.x. I have tried some basic query but couldn't go further. My expertise is not sql.

```
select Id, PendingAtLevel FROM Approvals WHERE SPLIT_PART(Approvers,'],[',?) LIKE '%boss%'
```

I expect to see following result:

```
Id  PendingAtLevel
3       3
11      3
```

Comment: Don't use composite data types like arrays and JSON, then your queries will be simpler and usually faster too.

Comment: This is really a bad design.

Comment: Is there anyway I can achieve what I have described above.